# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'module') when loading keras saved model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am loading the keras saved model and getting the error.

```
new_model=load_model("my_model.h5")
new_model.summary()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\phd python projects\tensorflow_img_class\src\tensorflow ui.py", line 43, in <module>
    new_model=load_model("my_model.h5")#, custom_objects = custom_objects)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 225, in _deserialize_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 458, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 300, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 764, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 626, in __init__
    super(Lambda, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 128, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'module')
```

I have already checked the Keras version that I have used to save the model and my current Keras on computer. Both are same and are Keras 2.2.4

When I am tried to load model by

```
model= tf.keras.models.load_model(
"saved_models/",
custom_objects=None,
compile=True)
```

I am getting permission denied error as following:

```
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'saved_models/', errno = 13, error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

I am not able to resolve this issue and would appreciate some help

Comment: Do not call load_model with a folder, you have to call tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_models/my_model.h5')

Comment: tried and not getting this error NameError: name 'feature_extractor_url' is not defined

Comment: That is error is unrelated to the question, we can only answer to what is in the question. If you have more issues you should open a new question, but before that make sure that it is not a small code issue like typos in variable names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't build the model using Keras 2.2.4, you built it using `tf.keras`, and now you are loading it with `keras`. Both modules are not actually compatible and this i why you get an error.

The simple solution is to never mix `keras` with `tf.keras`.

Comment: please check the update. am getting permission denied error now

Comment: @user3050590 you put a folder, not a filename,  to load_model you forgot the my_model.h5 in the path.

Comment: checked this solution https://github.com/Microsoft/AutonomousDrivingCookbook/issues/45 but don't know which file do I need to edit..